# How to change a linked Gravatar account from Stack Overflow

Tags: support, user-accounts, gravatar

I have linked a Gravatar account to my Stack Overflow account (I don't remember doing it, but it is linked), and the Gravatar account that is linked is not the one I am using. I don't even remember which is the account that is linked. And I don't know its credentials as well.

How can I link another Gravatar account to my profile? I didn't see any option for that anywhere.

Comment: Change your email address to the one associated with the proper Gravatar.

Comment: @hims056 no it's not. Gravatar is not OpenID provider it's just used for the avatar/profile picture.

Comment: As for the question, you can upload a custom picture, just hover over your avatar when viewing your own profile and you'll see "change picture" link allowing you to upload new picture.

Comment: @Sha - I thought he may be talking about linking more than one accounts (And by gravatar he mean [Wordpress](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175358/187824))

Comment: @hims056 might be, on second look he's using custom image and not Gravatar.

Comment: I am using custom pic since i can't link to proper gravatar...